# Electrical Requirements and Current/Voltage Ratings

Tags: pcb-design, component-selection

Good afternoon everyone.

I need to purchase PCB components and I need to make sure I have the right idea.  A little background.  I will have a socket connector embedded in plastic, running from end to end.  These sockets will be in parallel, one for + and another for -.  They will be around 24 inches long.  I need them to potentially carry 250 Watts.  I will have pins attached to pcb boards to connect to these sockets, powering what is in between.

The sockets I am looking at state Current Rating of 1.0A and Voltage rating of 250V ac/dc.  Is it safe to assume that I could use a power supply of 48V and 5A, or are these specific ratings?

Comment: Those are independent ratings - the sockets can carry up to 1 Amp, at up to 250 Volts.

Answer (score 2):

Connectors don't "carry watts", they carry current.

**Current rating** of your connectors has to meet or exceed the design current of your circuit. This is to prevent overheating of the contacts and excessive voltage drop across the contacts.

**Voltage rating** of your connectors has to meet or exceed the voltage difference between adjacent pins and between the pins and anything else in close proximity.

> Is it safe to assume that I could use a power supply of 48V and 5A, ...?

Definitely not.